# How To Create User Accounts for Website on LAMP Server?

Tags: mysql, web-services, oauth, webserver, lamp

I am working on a Linux, Apache2, MySQL and PHP server setup currently. I have a dynamic website up and running. I want to create a register / sign-in portal. How would I go about creating a user authentication using PHP and MySQL? I can't find anything on Stack Overflow, and I've searched over google but I'm only finding outdated information.

Comment: If you want username and password when accessing the website, you could try adding a .htaccess file. Example: http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/

More information about what HTACCESS is: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html